# MySQL incorrect format in date() in a SELECT succeeds, but fails in CREATE TABLE AS SELECT. Is that correct?

Tags: mysql

This works:

```
select date('2016-01-11 06:40:10.188918 UTC') as bbb;
```

with the result:

```
January, 11 2016 00:00:00
```

But this fails:

```
drop table if exists temp_junk;

create temporary table temp_junk as
select date('2016-01-11 06:40:10.188918 UTC') as bbb;
```

with the error:

```
Data truncation: Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2016-01-11 06:40:10.188918 UTC'
```

Is this the correct behavior?

Why doesn't it fail (or succeed) in both places?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fc015/1/0

MORE INFO on @Michael - sqlbot's suggestion:

```
SELECT @@VERSION, @@SQL_MODE
```

Result (in my Google SQL database)

```
@@VERSION  @@SQL_MODE                                  
-------------------------------------------------------
5.6.26     STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

And in SQLFiddle:

```
@@VERSION   @@SQL_MODE
5.6.21      STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: Do you really intend to truncate your timestamp to a date?

Comment: No. It's just a minimal example of the behavior. I ran across it using STR_TO_DATE() but that unnecessarily complicates the example.

Comment: Really weird indeed. The manual seems to indicate that this should be allowed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date.

Comment: "Truncated" errors occur when you try to put a value into a column that can't hold it. The first query doesn't put the value into a table, it just returns it from the select.

Comment: @Lukas Eder it appears to be failing on the timezone "UTC", but the fact that it succeeds in one case and fails in the other (for whatever reason) is really what I'm trying to understand here

Comment: @Barmar but the table doesn't exist yet, so wouldn't the table just get created with whatever type the select returns? Or is mysql trying to guess what the type of the column will be before it actually runs the select, and guesses wrong?

Comment: I think something like that is going on. The documentation doesn't say how it determines the data types, but indicates that it may not be what you expect. Like varchar can become char.

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION, @@SQL_MODE;` will provide insight into the reason for this behavior.  I suspect you will find something "strict" in the sql_mode which impacts writing values to tables but not expressions in the wild.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot STRICT_TRANS_TABLES I'm not sure what it means but definitely a clue. Thank you! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug. I would report it as such to http://bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Michael - sqlbot's comment above, unsetting the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES sql_mode allows it to work:

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

or

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

I'm not sure I understand these modes, but some info is available at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables